# Google Drive and CORS Cross Domain Requests

Tags: google-drive-api, cors, google-api-js-client

I have been wracking my brain trying to figure out how to download a file from Drive in Internet Explorer. It seems that Cross Domain security concerns are preventing this.

A simple 'GET' using XMLHttpRequest works fine in Chrome and Firefox, because it supports request headers, which allow the browser to request a CORS response, as shown in the following lines of code:

```
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open('GET', file.downloadUrl);
   xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
   xhr.onload = function() {
      callback(xhr.responseText);
   };
   xhr.send();
```

IE does not support the request headers, purportedly for security reasons. With no ability to download content in this unfortunately popular browser, I am completely stuck.

My question is this - how in the world are these other applications dealing with this issue? Are they using a server side proxy of some sort, and funneling all drive requests through their own back end? That seems rather arduous at this point. Or, is there some way to access the drive file upon launch, that I am not aware of?

I have seen some solutions that require files on both servers, which are not an option as far as I am aware. Does Google Drive have the ability to respond with CORS without the request header, or is there another API that I am not aware of that supports some sort of callback from an iframe within the Drive domain?

I am pretty much dead in the water at this point. Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Sorry to have to ask any questions having to do with MS products.

Comment: Have you considered the JS Client for the Drive API: http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/09/introducing-javascript-support-for.html

Comment: Yep, the code shown above was taken from the Download section. It works great in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, just not in IE. I looked for an alternative method, but there does not seem to be a way to do the CORS auth header within IE, or a byte range header (for a partial download).

Comment: Hey Dano64, If CORS are not working on IE we want to fix this. Could you let me know exactly what we would need to do on Google's end in order to fix this for IE? I will then file a bug with our eng team and I'll try to get a quick fix.

Comment: Also a way to show the current problem on IE would be awesome - like if you could have some page online somewhere that our eng team could use to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I created a fiddle, which demonstrates the problem.

(http://jsfiddle.net/qsWd5/)

Comment: I doubt this is a bug on your end, because it is really MSIE's fault. I wish I knew what to do, to work around it. I suspect other apps are using server libraries to access Drive data, then channeling the info to users from their backend. This seems to be the most viable solution at this point. Unless there is a way to trick IE, by using an iFrame. I assume that this is how other content is accessed within the api. I would be interested to see what the engineers think.

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to provide an endpoint within the api that serves up the content, similarly to the way that the metadata is accessed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the issue is with IE not allowing you to add or not passing the `Authorization` header, you could try passing the Access Token using the `access_token` URL parameter which has the same behavior as the `Authorization` header:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', file.downloadUrl + '&access_token=' + accessToken);
xhr.onload = function() {
   callback(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. This works well in Chrome. It is still throwing an error in IE, but that may be related to the fact that the site is running in http and the downloadUrl is always https. I will install a security certificate tonight and try again with a test page that is https enabled.

Comment: SUCCESS! Thanks for your assistance.  

This works great in IE now. Just to summarize the necessary conditions to download a Google Drive Item in IE:  
  
1) use XDomainRequest as opposed to XMLHttpRequest in IE.  
2) pass the Access Token in the querystring, as shown above.  
3) use HTTPS, because the XDomainRequest object does not allow combo with HTTP.  
  
See the article below for more info on the problems with IE8, IE9 and upcoming IE10.  
  
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx