# Google Drive drive file download with "Access Data Sources Accross Domains" on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-api, google-drive-api, microsoft-edge

I'm using Google Drive API v2 to get files contents using a function like the one it is shown on 
[Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) (see **downloadFile** function).

This works on Chrome, Firefox without problems but this is not the case for IE (Edge, 11 etc.).

If a user enables the `Access Data Sources Accross Domains` options in IE options, the request is completed and a response with the file's contents is returned.

So, is there an alternative to get a file's content from Google Drive without this security problem in IE?

Is there a configuration that misses from the request to send or it is an issue of the implementation of the API end-point

> https://doc-14-18-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/.../file_id?e=download&gd=true

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what are the detailed symptoms, console errors etc

Comment: What I get in IE console is "Request header accept was not present in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers list.
 XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied." This is CORS related error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried what this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434704/google-drive-and-cors-cross-domain-requests) suggests and now I pass the access token not in header
as the [Google Drive guide page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) shows but as a parameter in the url, i.e.

```
'&access_token=' + accessToken
```

That way there is no problem in Internet Explorer. I guess this is something it needs to be clarified on Google Drive examples.